# Loop Fails if file in list does not exist; how to handle this error

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I have script that runs on server reboot, to loop through the applications under 
 a directory and start them after a reboot is complete.  Recently, I've made a refactor where it looks though a text file first for a list of applications to start.  If the list is not available, it starts everything:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd $HOME/services

startup()
{
    service=$(basename "$appName")

    #PLEASE NOTE: I've also tried this following if statement with [ -d $appName ] on the same line as [ -e $appName/bin/start.sh ] && [ $service != mongo ], with the same result.

    if [ -d $appName ]
    then
        if [ -e $appName/bin/start.sh ] && [ $service != mongo ];
        then
            cd $appName/bin
            echo "`date -u` - Stopping current instance of $appName"
            ./stop.sh $appName
            echo "`date -u` - Starting $appName"
            ./start.sh
        else
            echo "`date -u` - No start script found for $appName"
        fi
    else
        echo "`date -u` - Cannot find directory for $appName. Proceeding to next service in list"
    fi
}

cd $HOME/apps;

if [ -e $HOME/dependencies/list.txt ];
then
    echo "`date -u` - Reading from startlist.txt"
    while read appName; do
        startup $appName
    done <list.txt
    echo "`date -u` - Completed start up based on list"
else
    echo "`date -u` - Cannot find input list; starting all processes"
    for appName in $HOME/apps/* ; do
        startup $appName
    done
    echo "`date -u` - Completed startup for all processes"
fi
```

This works if the script is not available, and if it is available.  However, it fails if there is a service that does not exist included in the list.  For example, lets say that in list.txt, there is the following:

```
EmailServer
EmployeeProfiles
FakeApp
HAProxy
```

When I start the list, it will start EmailServer and EmployeeProfiles fine.  When it gets to FakeApp, it will return that the application does not exist in the services/ directory.  However, it will then do that for every service that comes after, and not start them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your problem is caused by your use of relative paths when reading from  the list. When the second appName is read, the working directory is still the one set for the first, causing `[ -d $appName ]` to fail.

Easiest fix is probably to use `startup $HOME/app/$appName` instead of `startup $appName`.

Comment: @Quasímodo: My guess: The script is verbatim, but the OPs analysis of the cause of the error is off. Please enlighten us to whom is correct, SVIll.

Comment: The scripts itself is verbatum; the only change I made here was the names of the applications it reads through in the text file.  I'm going to try the absolute paths, and will get back to you on the results.

Comment: This seems to have worked.  I changed the paths in the startup() function to use absolute paths, and the script now seems to work fine.  Thanks!